# Symfony 3 Maximum File Size Upload Constraint in Controller or FormBuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, upload

This controller needs to check if a file uploaded through a FileType FormBuilder in Symfony is larger than 128M before processing it.
I have tried using a constraint within the formbuilder, without any success.

The goal is to validate the size before even downloading it from the user's upload.

**The FormBuilder**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use AppBundle\Entity\AdmCompteSessionRepository;

class UploadType extends AbstractType implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fichier_ine', FileType::class, array('required' => false))
            ->add('sendfile', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Vérifier les numéros'])
        ;
    }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
    public function searchFormAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SearchType');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $verifyForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\VerifyType');
        $verifyForm->handleRequest($request);

        $uploadForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UploadType');
        $uploadForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->get('session')->set('search', $form->getData());
            /*$admCompteSession = $form->getData()["candidat_serie_bac"];

            $admCompteSession->setNombreRech($admCompteSession->getNombreRech() + 1);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($admCompteSession);
            $em->flush();*/
            return $this->redirectToRoute('results');
        }

        $series = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:BacCandidatSerie')
            ->findAll();

        if ($verifyForm->isSubmitted() && $verifyForm->isValid()) {

            $ine = $verifyForm->getData(); //key "numero_ine" contains the data
            $ineValidator = new CodeValidator($ine['numero_ine']);
            if($ineValidator->testINE()){
                //print "numéro validé"
                return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'verifyForm' => $verifyForm->createView(),
                    'valid' => true,
                    'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
                    'series' => $series,
                    'isTested' => true,
                    'isInvalid' => false
                ));
            }
            else{
                return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'verifyForm' => $verifyForm->createView(),
                    'valid' => false,
                    'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
                    'series' => $series,
                    'isTested' => true,
                    'isInvalid' => true,
                ));
            }
        }

       if ($uploadForm->isSubmitted() && $uploadForm->isValid()) {
           $targetDirectory = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../var/public/';
           $fileData = $uploadForm['fichier_ine']->getData();
           $exportCSV = $targetDirectory . 'LOT_INE_' . uniqid('IT_ID_') . '_KEY_' . (string)rand() . '.csv';
           CodeValidator::batchINE($fileData, $exportCSV);

           $response = new BinaryFileResponse($exportCSV);
           $response->setContentDisposition( ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
               'verification.csv');
           $response->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
           return $response;
       }

        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'verifyForm' => $verifyForm->createView(),
            'valid' => false,
            'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
            'series' => $series,
            'isTested' => false,
            'isInvalid' => false
        ));
    }
```

I would like to achieve this with minimal structural changes, without adding any Entity (so in FormBuilder or in Controller function would be ideal).
Symfony does reject files that are too large, however it stills download it whilst processing the request which is an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found somehow a solution using jQuery... because Symfony validation seemed borked in 3.1

In the TWIG view:

````
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#{{ uploadForm.fichier_ine.vars.id }}").on('change', function () {
                    if (this.files[0].size > 128000000) {
                        alert("Erreur, fichier trop volumineux. Le fichier doit peser moins de 128M");
                        this.value = "";
                    }
                }
            )
        })
    </script>```

Directly pulling the id from the Twig vars.
Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.
````